# Using Get-ChildItem with a string variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm using Get-ChildItem to save file locations that match user-input parameters. I can't seem to figure out (I'm new to powershell) how to use string variables with cmdlets.

I'll define $search_param as it is in my script below.

I've tried using the built in debugger on powershell ise, and if anything it's confused me even more.

This is where I found that replacing the use of '$search_param' with the actual value of $search_param produced a csv output, but using '$search_param' gives no output. Some useful information might be that I defined $search_param with double quotations.

The line that is causing all the issues is:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\USER\' -recurse '$search_param'
```

$search_param is defined as:

```
| where { $_.name -like "*peanut*" -or $_.name -like "*butter*" -or $_.name -like "*test*"} 
| where { $_.extension -in ".txt",".csv",".docx" } 
| where { $_.CreationTime -ge "08/07/1998" -and $_.CreationTime -le "08/07/2019" } 
| select FullName | Export-Csv -Path .\SearchResults.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Funnily enough I had it all working before I went to lunch and came back to a different story..

I'm using Export-csv in another piece of my script and that is working as intended.

I may have touched something small that isn't related to the line I provided as I think this should be working..

Comment: You have a string describing code, not actual code, so you can't run it as is. You could use `Invoke-Expression` to make PowerShell read it as code though. Something like `Invoke-Expression "Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\USER\' -recurse $search_param"`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thannks! That seemed to work. But I was under the impression that the variable $search_param would be expanded. Why doesn't -recurse $search_param  work?

Comment: Well, for one, you have `'$search_param'` in single quotes, so it will not expand the string. In double quotes it would (i.e. `"$search_param"`), but it is still just going to be a string, not actual script. Even expanding the string I don't think it will do what you expect it to.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into string behavior some more.. I just don't see how else I can evaluate user input that changes how a query is structured..

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Is it generally bad powershell practice to rely on Invoke-Expression?

Comment: Yes, it is. I think the best way to accomplish what you're trying is probably to reconsider how you are constructing and using `$search_param`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Technician's comment:

You can use invoke expression to "evaluate or run a specified string as a command and return the results of the expression or command."

```
Invoke-Expression "Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\SGouldin\' -recurse $search_param"
```

From a little bit of research, relying on invoke expression isn't always the best practice.
In my case, I needed it because of the way I was attempting to handle user input (some weeeeird string concatenation/joins).